# Multiple flags in one int value

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a int variable which hold multiple flags, for instance:

```
int styles = ExpandableComposite.TITLE_BAR | ExpandableComposite.TWISTIE | ExpandableComposite.EXPANDED;
```

I can test the presence of a flag

```
boolean expanded = (styles & ExpandableComposite.EXPANDED) != 0;
```

How can I clear the value of a flag from `styles`, i.e. dynamically remove `ExpandableComposite.EXPANDED`, without knowing the exact flags which are set in `styles`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is an old C idiom, still working in Java:

```
styles &= ~ExpandableComposite.EXPANDED;
```

However these days (>= Java 1.5) you should consider using:

- [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) (see [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html))
- [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)
- [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)

Comment: Thank you, works great. And yes, I would be using EnumSet but I'm working against an API - Eclipse - which needs to support 1.4 .